# this is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting into express and mongoose and have made a `mongoose  statics` as such.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const trainerSchema = require('./trainer.model');

trainerSchema.statics = {
    create : (data, cb) => {
        const trainer = new this(data);
        trainer.save(cb);
    },

    get: (query, cb) => {
        this.find(query, cb);
    },

    getByName: (query, cb) => {
        this.find(query, cb);
    },

    update: (query, updateData, cb) => {
        this.findOneAndUpdate(query,
            {$set: updateData},{new: true}, cb);
    },

    delete: (query, cb) =>{
        this.findOneAndDelete(query,cb);
    }
}

const trainerModel = mongoose.model('Trainer', 
trainerSchema);

module.exports = trainerModel;
```

but whenever i try to create a `trainer` modek i get this error: `TypeError: this is not a constructor`

and i don't know why this happens, because i thought this refered back to the schema model.

Comment: Because `this` is the *instance`, not the constructor creating the instance.

Comment: did you tried using a normal function instead of arrow function like - 
get: function(query, cb)  {
        this.find(query, cb);
    },

Comment: What kind of object is `new this(data);` supposed to create?  Which constructor is `this` supposed to be?  Can only help you when we know that.  Also, using a fat arrow on a method is usually the wrong choice because `this` is a lexical value, not a desired object value.